# How would I get the variable "message" from the link and make it update in the database?

Tags: php, postback

hey so i am making a site where people can send a message and i want to put it in my database. but they can update the message. here is the link i am using http://example.com/file.php?message=hi&referral=1 but when accessing it i receive this error

> 0 Row updated, added hi to locker .

and it is an error because no rows were updated

```
<?php

define("MYSQL_HOST", "localhost");
define("MYSQL_PORT", "3306");
define("MYSQL_DB", "db");
define("MYSQL_TABLE", "table");
define("MYSQL_USER", "user");
define("MYSQL_PASS", "pass");
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$referral =            $_GET['refferal'];
$message =           $_GET['message'];

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".MYSQL_DB.".".MYSQL_TABLE." SET message=(?) WHERE referral=(?) "))) 
{

  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->bind_param('ds', $message, $referral);
if (!$stmt->execute()) 
{
  echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
else
{
  printf("%d Row updated, added ".$message." to locker ".$referral." .\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
}
?>
```

Comment: $_GET['message'] will give you the value of message

Comment: how would i use that and put it into the database? @DhavalChheda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a url as `www.google.com`, and you want to pass certain data attributes from a url parameter. The link would like something like the following for this example.

`www.google.com?color=blue`

You would do the following to retrieve the value from the URL.

```
// First lets define this variable so we do not get any undefined variable warnings in the error log.
$color = NULL; 

// second would be lets validate that this get parameter is set and not empty.
if ( !empty($_GET['color']) ) { 


 // We will then define the REQUEST to a variable for later calling.
    $color = $_REQUEST['color']; 
}
```

Then you can simply `echo $color` and it will have the value of `blue`.

You can then simply apply your $color variable to your database statement.

Lastly, You have a typo in your REQUEST for `refferal` where as it should be `referral`.